# IF multiple conditions PowerShell

Tags: powershell, if-statement, multiple-conditions

Why does it always returns me "Non valid input..."?

```
$var = Read-Host -prompt "Insert a number from 1 to 6"
    
if (($var -ne 1)-or ($var -ne 2)-or ($var -ne 3)-or ($var -ne 4)-or ($var -ne 5)-or ($var -ne 6)){
  Write-Host "Non valid input..."
  pause; exit
} else {
  Write-Host "OK."
  pause; exit
}
```

Comment: If you use `-or` your evaluation will be true if any of them are true so pretty much always true the way you have it written.  Try instead `if ($var -notin 1..6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using an `-or` operator to look at a single value.  Say you enter 5. That's not equal to 1, therefore the block is triggered and `Write-Host "Non valid input..."` is written to the console.  If you are checking something is within a range check against the high and low end of the range like:

```
if ( ($var -lt 1) -or ($var -gt 6) ){
    Write-Host "Non valid input..."
    pause
} 
else {
    Write-Host "OK."
    pause
}
```

You can also constrain `$Var` to be and `[Int]` with:

```
[Int]$Var = Read-Host -prompt "Insert a number from 1 to 6"
```

That will help limit input to whole numbers...

However, this type of thing is usually wrapped in a loop so a re-prompt can occur if an unacceptable input is made.

Comment: Thank you very much, i appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$ExcludeValues=@(1, 3, 5, 6)

$var = Read-Host -prompt "Insert a number from 1 to 6"
    
if ($var -in $ExcludeValues)
{
  "Non valid input..."
} 
else 
{
  "OK"
}
```